# How to `forceFetch` multiple times in Relay?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, relayjs

We have a really simple Relay container with the following shape:

```
const ItemLoader = Relay.createContainer(Item, {
  fragments: {
    foo: (): any => Relay.QL`
      fragment on Foo {
        points
        nickname
        status
        id
        type
        version
    }
  }
}
```

We want to poll this every 1 second. Within the Item mount method, we have the following:

```
const forceFetch = () => {
  console.log('tick')
  relay.forceFetch()
}

let intervalId = setInterval(forceFetch, 1000)
```

The first one is triggered and drawn back successfully. However, no further requests are being made (though we are seeing "tick", "tick").

Is there anyway to forceFetch to actually forceFetch when no variables are changing?

Comment: Are you calling `forceFetch` on `this.props.relay` inside the component ? It would help that you paste the entire code.

Comment: Yes, its inside

Comment: Can you paste the whole code ?

Comment: forceFetch should actually fetch it again each time, so the problem lies within your code